# How do I alias a member function in class space?

Tags: c++, function, class, alias, member-functions

I would like to be able to call the same member function by multiple names from an object of the class.

For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

class Log
{
public:
    Log(std::string str)
        : log(str)
    {}

    void print() const
    {
        puts(log.c_str());
    }
    const auto& output = print;    // attempting to alias. does not work

private:
    std::string log;
};

int main()
{
    Log log("LOG: Log started.");
    log.print();
    log.output();    // both should call the same function.
    return 0;
}
```

This code yields this error for me (gcc 7.3.0)

```
main.cpp:15:15: error: non-static data member declared with placeholder ‘const auto’
         const auto& output = print;    // attempting to alias. does not work
               ^~~~
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:25:13: error: ‘class Log’ has no member named ‘output’
         log.output();    // both should call the same function.
```

How can I define an alias for a function name?

Comment: `void output() const { print(); }`?

Comment: @Passer By That is not exactly an alias, I would have to adjust that function when the signature of `print` changes.

Comment: @stimulate Can you explain a bit more what you're considering to be an _alias_? There are things like `using` or such. Anyways what you have is just invalid syntax. It sounds you have an XY-problem so far, what's the use case you need that for?

Comment: I consider an alias a second name for something, here the function. `using` only works for types as far as I know... But it should act just like that. an alias should not have to own any kind of information accept the alternative name.

Comment: The use case is the example.

Comment: @stimulate Adjusting the signature of `output` to the one of `print` on changes will be your least problem - you'll have to adjust all *calls* of your function, no matter which version of you use - and *these* might be numerous...

Comment: @Aconcagua yes, thats true, but that is just in the nature of changing the signature of a function. The question was if I can define an alias for a function name, which is not the same as defining a wrapper for the function. Honestly, it was probably not clear enough.

Comment: @stimulate About use cases (general consideration): You should look a little farther, your example is not a *real* use case. That one is hidden behind the question "Why do you want to be able to do this?" - and a possible answer might be: "I want prevent old code from breaking by supporting a deprecated legacy interface and delegating it to the new one."

Comment: @Aconcagua my actual answer would just be that I want to learn the best possible practices. The functions I need this for of an interface I am currently developing, and although their signatures probably won't change, they might, and I was wondering if there was a perfect solution for this, which might even enable more advanced techniques, who knows.

Comment: @stimulate But why do you care then for one single extra call to be changed? You have defined an *inline(!)* wrapper, so it won't ever appear in compiled code and you *effectively* get a true alias. What else do you want?

Comment: If you absolutely insist on: extending @PasserBy 's initial comment, such that it would survive any changes of `print` signature: `template <typename ... TT> auto output(TT&& ... tt) { return print(std::forward(tt)...); }` - it contains all the tricks you wanted, but I don't consider it "best practice"...

Comment: @Aconcagua that is the answer of Zereges, which I accepted. I didnt want to care about a second function... I know, thats perfectionistic but I was looking for a language feature for this.

Comment: I see... Somehow, my browser regularly misses the site updates, so I did not see the answer in time...

Comment: @Aconcagua: doesn't survive to const/volatile changes, neither reference (of `this`) or c-ellipsis usage (a la `printf`).

Comment: And taking reference of that method might be problematic.

Comment: @Jarod42 good you point that out, but I think I will have to readjust the function anyways. The language feature I was hoping for does not exist in C++, which is kind of disappointing, but maybe some day it will get implemented. (i dunno, i think it could be really useful to call "perfectly" the same function from different names.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would go with variadic template with perfect forwarding

```
class Log
{
public:
    Log(std::string str)
        : log(str)
    {}

    void print() const
    {
        puts(log.c_str());
    }

    template<typename... Ts>
    auto output(Ts&&... ts) const -> decltype(print(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...))
    {
        return print(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
    }

private:
    std::string log;
};
```

If signature of `print` changes, there is no need to change anything in `output` (apart from `const`ness, that has to be changed accordingly). The only issue is verboseness of `output` signature and duplication of *call* to print in trailing return type (which is unnecessary in C++14). The good thing is that it works even if another overload of `print` is added! Another *issue* would be in IDE, which wouldn't *forward* documentation comments.

Another option would be to introduce member variables referencing the function.

Comment: Indeed quite verbose, but it does what I need.

Comment: *"apart from constness"*, you miss `volatile`, references (of `this`) and C-ellipsis (as `printf`), `noexcept`, non deducible template argument (`std::make_unique`).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, the language does not provide a mechanism to define an alias for a member function.

However, if you are willing to use a non-member function that calls the member function, you have the ability to define an alias.

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

namespace MyApp
{
   class Log
   {
      public:
         Log(std::string str)
            : log(str)
         {}

         void print() const
         {
            puts(log.c_str());
         }

      private:
         std::string log;
   };

   void print(Log const& log)
   {
      log.print();
   }

   auto& output = print; // OK
   auto& write = print;  // OK
}

int main()
{
   MyApp::Log log("LOG: Log started.");
   MyApp::print(log);  // Works OK
   MyApp::output(log); // Works OK
   MyApp::write(log);  // Works OK
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I am aware of this solution, but I want the alias to behave just like the original function, i.e. I can call it with `log.output()`

Comment: @stimulate, I don't think you can do that.

Comment: @stimulate Just playing around, based on this answer, making your original approach work: `class Log { public: static auto constexpr output = &Log::print; }; int main() { Log log; (log.*Log::output)(); }` - calling print via member function pointer. Not really matching your question, but still nice to see (*"I want to learn"*).

Answer (score 1):

You can, the problem in your provided code is the `auto` on a non-static member variable.

Here are some examples on how to do it, but calling the member is not pretty at all. If this is a user accessed API, I would personally go with wrapping print.

```cpp
class Log {
public:
    Log(std::string str)
            : log(str) {
    }

    void print() const {
        puts(log.c_str());
    }

    // Using auto.
    static constexpr auto output = &print;

    // Using function pointer.
    using print_ptr_t = void (Log::*)() const;
    print_ptr_t output2 = &Log::print;

private:
    std::string log;
};

Log l{ "test log" };
(l.*l.output)();
(l.*l.output2)();
```